# Get url link from the web using python

Tags: python

So I am trying to write a script that will allow to search for a certain place and get the coordinates. I am very limited with the packages because I'm not allow download any packages that does not already comes with python 2.7.

```
import webbrowser

location = input('Enter your location: ')

webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/maps/place/'+location)
```

My browser opens and the url changes to

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Washington+Monument/@38.8894838,-77.0374678,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x89b7b7a1be0c2e7f:0xe97346828ed0bfb8
```

From there, I want to get the new url so I can strip it to just have the coordinates. Anyone one know how to get the new url the browser creates?

Comment: If the user is entering the location information, why not just strip the coordinates from there?  Why bother with a browser at all?

Comment: @JohnGordon the user will enter something like Washington.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> text = urllib.urlopen('https://www.google.com/maps/place/washington').read()
>>> p = text.find('cacheResponse([[[')
>>> p
228
>>> text[228: 300]
'cacheResponse([[[26081602.52827102,-95.67706800000001,37.06250000000001]'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)'s [Python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps/place/Washington')
>>> driver.current_url
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Washington,+DC/@38.8992651,-77.1546507,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x89b7c6de5af6e45b:0xc2524522d4885d2a
```

Comment: OP says he is not allowed to install any packages. However good approach nonetheless